# Drop-down menu that shows the average of multiple rating criteria on Fivestar

Tags: 6, rating

I am working on customizing the Fivestar module, to allow the rating of multiple criteria.

The Fivestar rating should show a drop-down menu, in which the user could rate the object on 4 different criteria. The resulting rating should be the average value of those four criteria.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on where to start on this?

edit: i am running drupal 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved: I wrote the code to paste in the template, and added a module to sort by votes.

See [Dropdown menu that shows average of multiple rating criteria](http://drupal.org/node/1294874).